# Taz About self defense

Tags: sources-mekorot

In this [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12897/self-defense-in-a-case-of-ones-capital-not-a-capital-case?noredirect=1&lq=1), user3109 on the comment refers to certain Taz (Y.D. 179 S'4), that talks about self defense. It seems that there was a typo, and the source is incorrect.

Where does the Taz talks about self defense?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the reference was to סעיף קטן ד in the Taz rather than in Shulchan Aruch; [His comment in ס"ק ד](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.179.7?lang=bi&with=Turei%20Zahav&lang2=en) seems to be relevant

ט"ז יורה דעה סימן קעט
(ד) מותר לחבר שלא יזיקוהו. דאין לך דבר שעומד בפני פיקוח נפש משמע כאן דאם פיקוח נפש תלוי בעבירה שכשעושה עבירה יכול להנצל מותר לו לעשות כן מעצמו עבירה ההיא כמו הכא שעל ידי שעובר על לאו דחובר חבר מציל עצמו:

Comment: excellent answer! And welcome to Mi Yodea! BTW, you might improve your answer by linking to an online text where they can read it formatted and in context. For instance, here: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.179.7?lang=bi&with=Turei%20Zahav&lang2=en

And to note that the original citation seems correct.

You can indent text using the > symbol at the start of a paragraph.
Also, a translation would be even better.

Comment: Is there a way to fit the formatting to by RTL in the answer?
Thank you for the kind words and tips!

Comment: I don't think so. Stackexchange uses markdown, and markdown doesn't have a right-align option.

Comment: just for the record - I posted this as an answer and deleted it when no-one acknowledged it....

Comment: @Dov I remember your answer, and I will no accept that either, for the same reason. It's not specifically talks about self defense